# asp.net dnx ef migrations add ERROR

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

when I type :dnx ef migrations add initial,this error apear:

System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create instance of type 'System.String' because it is missing a public parameterless constructor.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.CreateInstance(Type type)
......

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still with this issue but this [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/issues/343) worked for me.

The last message said:
Changing:

```
configuration.Get("Data:DefaultConnection:Connectionstring")
```

with this:

```
configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]
```